# Kill buffer when closing a frame only if that's the only frame showing that buffer?

Tags: buffers

How can I kill a buffer when closing a frame only if that's the only frame showing that buffer?  Is there a way to check if the buffer in the selected frame is not in any other frame?

Comment: Please clarify if you mean ["window" when you say "frame"](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/whats-the-difference-between-a-buffer-a-file-a-window-and-a-frame).  Frames can have multiple windows, so it's not clear what you would want to do in the latter case.

Comment: @Dan Thanks, I know what frame and widow refer to in the emacs community, though! I actually found my answer here. Should I close mine as a duplicate? I'll try to find the link and get back.

Comment: @Dan Here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2888/kill-buffer-when-frame-is-deleted